# Pivot Assistance

Tags: sql, pivot-table

Tried several ways of combining multiple rows into a single row, with no luck.  I am using SQL 2008. Haven't used Pivot in the past, so this is sort of new. The Pivot function isn't working or I may be looking at it wrong. Here is the current output that is needed to be combined into one row.

```
+--------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
|     Agent_ID | EvalForm_ID | 1.0 Compliance |                Reg_Fail                 | Marketing Guidelines |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
|        16738 |      225777 |                |                                         |                      |
|        16738 |      225777 |                |                                         |                    1 |
|        16738 |      225777 |                |                                   1     |                      |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
 Agent_ID   EvalForm_ID 1.0 Compliance  Reg_Fail    Marketing Guidelines
   16738        225777                       1      1
```

Also here is the orginial code that I am using...again, I've tried everthing. If you can assist, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Select DISTINCT TR.Agent_ID
  ,TR.EvalForm_ID
  ,TR.[1.0 Compliance]
  ,TR.REg_Fail,TR.[Marketing Guidelines]


FROM #TrendResults AS TR

 WHERE TR.EvalForm_ID ='225777'

Group BY TR.Agent_ID,TR.EvalForm_ID,TR.Reg_Fail,TR.[Marketing Guidelines],TR.[1.0     
Compliance]
```

Comment: What are you trying to PIVOT?  What column?  It looks like your sample data disappeared from your question.

Comment: Your code does not include an attempt to use the pivot function.

Comment: Agent_ID EvalForm_ID 1.0 Compliance Reg_Fail Marketing Guidelines
16738 225777   
16738 225777   1
16738 225777  1

Comment: I didn't use the Pivot example, beacuse it would have confused everyone...figured it would be easier not showing it.

Comment: You need to have a column that you sum or average. I cannot see sample data in your question.

Comment: @DanBracuk: that's why he is asking for pivot assistance.

Comment: @user2133330 Please edit your original question with your sample data and then the desired result of the query.  Please don't place it in the comments.

Comment: Added the sample, but not able to import as a pic to show a better example...Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data and the desired result, you need to apply an aggregate function with a GROUP BY:

```
Select TR.Agent_ID
  ,TR.EvalForm_ID
  ,Max(TR.[1.0 Compliance]) [1.0 Compliance]
  ,Max(TR.REg_Fail)  REg_Fail
  ,Max(TR.[Marketing Guidelines]) [Marketing Guidelines]
FROM #TrendResults AS TR
WHERE TR.EvalForm_ID ='225777'
GROUP BY TR.Agent_ID, TR.EvalForm_ID;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74262/1)

Comment: Worked perfectly!!! Thank you. I have been pulling the rest of my hair out for something that was simple. (UGH!!!) Again thank you for the assistance.